# How to use jq with 'select(startswith("$variable"))'?

Tags: aws-cli, jq

I'm using `jq` to parse some output from AWS cli.

I'm trying to use `'select(startswith("$variable") )'` but for some reason it doesn't work even though when I use the variable's value it works properly.

Example:

```
itai@MacBook-Pro ~/src/Scripts - $ echo $App
Analytics
itai@MacBook-Pro ~/src/Scripts - $ aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name $StackName --region $region | jq -r '.Stacks[].Outputs[].OutputKey | select(startswith("Analytics") )'
AnalyticsAutoScalingGroup
itai@MacBook-Pro ~/src/Scripts - $ aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name $StackName --region $region | jq -r '.Stacks[].Outputs[].OutputKey | select(startswith("$App") )'
itai@MacBook-Pro ~/src/Scripts - $
```

I know I can use grep like so:

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name $StackName --region $region | jq -r '.Stacks[].Outputs[].OutputKey' | grep $App
```

But I prefer to use jq all along the command.

Am I doing it wrong or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also do it without using `--arg` or `--argjson`. In your case, since your variable holds a string value, you may do it like this.

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name $StackName --region $region |\
jq -r '.Stacks[].Outputs[].OutputKey | select(startswith('\"$App\"') )'
```

Notice I added single quotation marks and escaped the double-quotation marks around your variable

See here https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ on the "*How can environment variables be passed to a jq program? How can a jq program be parameterized*?" second answer.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the best way to pass the value of shell variables to a jq program is using the `-—arg` and/or `—-argjson` command-line options, as described in the manual. Environment variables can be passed in using `env`.

See also the https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ